# accessing nested terraform output values

Tags: terraform

I have an output

```
output "route_tables" {
  value       = module.oci_network.route_tables
}
```

That results in outputs in the following following format

```
route_tables = {
  "cool_systems" = [
    {
      "compartment_id" = {}
      "defined_tags" = {}
      "display_name" = "cool_systems"
      "freeform_tags" = {}
      "id" = "id-123"
      "route_rules" = [
        {
          "cidr_block" = "0.0.0.0/0"
          "description" = "sauce"
          "destination" = "car"
          "destination_type" = "CIDR_BLOCK"
          "network_entity_id" = "foo"
        },
      ]
      "state" = "AVAILABLE"
      "time_created" = ""
      "vcn_id" = "vcn-123"
    },
  ]
  "tool_systems" = [
    {
      "compartment_id" = ""
      "defined_tags" = {}
      "display_name" = "tool_systems"
      "freeform_tags" = {}
      "id" = ""
      "route_rules" = [
        {
          "cidr_block" = ""
          "description" = ""
          "destination" = "0.0.0.0/0"
          "destination_type" = "CIDR_BLOCK"
          "network_entity_id" = "foo"
        },
      ]
      "state" = "AVAILABLE"
      "time_created" = ""
      "vcn_id" = "vcn-123"
    },
  ]
}
```

The remote state is read in via a data sources called vcn.

I want to read the "id" attribute ("id" = "id-123") but this is nested within the cool_systems, from this data source how do I access this nested element?

If this was flat, it would simply be

```
route_table_id   = data.terraform_remote_state.vcn.outputs.route_tables.cool_systems.id
```

but that results in the following error.

| data.terraform_remote_state.vcn.outputs.route_tables.cool_systems is tuple with 1 element

How do I go about accessing this nested value?

Comment: Is it always the first element in the list of `cool_systems`? If so then `data.terraform_remote_state.vcn.outputs.route_tables.cool_systems.0.id` should be fine. If not then it's going to be much harder to get at this data.

Comment: so not necessarily, as I add more route tables I would really like help to make this dynamic.

Comment: You can provide an example that has multiple elements then? And how you would select that ID? Or do you just want all of the IDs?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR so I want to just return the value of "id" = "id-123" which is "id-123", this sits under route_tables and then cool_systems

Comment: Yes but what do you want to return if there are multiple IDs under `cool_systems`?

Comment: so that should not happen, there is 1 route table called "cool_systems", it should only ever have 1 value called id directly under cool_systems.

Comment: So then what's wrong with `data.terraform_remote_state.vcn.outputs.route_tables.cool_systems.0.id`? Or alternatively why is `cool_systems` a list instead of a map?

Comment: i misunderstood, I thought if i added a new route_table it would no longer be .cool_systems.0 I am going to try the above suggestion, thanks all.